Survey Data Set Manipulation
I hope to clarify here.
The first controlling data set from GPS I will call 'GPS'.  The second data set from LIDAR I will call 'LIDAR'.  I was able to take the horizontal position of the GPS data set, to find the exact value for the elevations of the LIDAR data set.  So essentially I have two values for elevation, at the same horizontal point.  At the time the LIDAR data was collected, the areas in question were cropped with soybean, which LIDAR has trouble penetrating.  I think a better way to pose the question is in using a list of wants from my data set,  I want:  a value to move the LIDAR surface, an uncertainty value after I move the data (preferably in elevation units), and a corresponding confidence level.  Based on surveying judgement, a fancy term for old surveyors who have never asked these questions before, we have enough data in our GPS set to make these determinations.  Thank you all again.

It depends on what you mean by "move."  You can find an analysis of what might be the same (or a similar problem) in my post at https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/55507.

I'm not sure the question as it stands contains enough information to be framed and answered as a purely statistical question, but it is of a practical nature and sounds like it would be a common issue within that field. I wouldn't be surprised if there are standard methodologies available to you that you're more likely to come across if you ask in the right place. There isn't a Remote Sensing Stack Exchange I notice that the GIS SE has a [remote-sensing] tag, which suggests it may be a better site to ask on.

The first thought that comes to mind is linear regression. Let's call your first dataset $Y$; this is your "ground truth" (feeble pun intended), what you know to be the correct elevation; your 2nd dataset $X$ is an "estimate" of this elevation. The way I read your question is that you want to adjust the estimate to be "close" to the true elevation. IN other words, you are trying to "calibrate" $X$ so it matches $Y$. One common way to do so is through regression, and the simplest form of it is linear regression.
The model looks like $y_i=b_0+b_1.x_i+\epsilon_i$ or $\hat y_i=b_0+b_1.x_i$, for all $i's$ in your datasets. $\hat y_i$ is the predicted value of $y$ for datapoint $x_i$. Ordinary Least Square (OLS) will give you the straight line which "best" predicts Y as a function of X (best, in the sense of minimizing the sum of the square errors, i.e. the sum of all $(y_i - \hat y_i)^2$. The output of the model will be the coefficients $b_0$ and $b_1$ and a coefficient of determination $R^2$ which tells you how well the linear regression matched the true data $Y$.
Now, there is no guaranty that all errors (i.e. $(y_i - \hat y_i)$) will be within 5% (or any $p$% for that matter) of the true $y_i$ values. There is not even a guaranty that $c$% (coverage) of the error terms will be within $p$% of the true $y_i$ values. But you can check this; you can compute normal tolerance intervals; see here for a good practical description. With this, you can see what proportion of the errors (coverage) fall within what percentage of the true value, with a level of confidence $(1-\alpha)$; so you have 3 variables to "play with"; the coverage, the confidence level (or significance), and the tolerance limits. See if your data happens to be "good enough" (e.g., it may be that you can show that 80% of the error terms are within 10% of the true elevation, with 95% confidence: is that good enough for your application? Up to you...).
As I said, there is no guaranty that you will find such a satisfactory combination. Your measurements X may be very poor (i.e. the error terms $\epsilon_i$ are large, with a large variability). You can try to improve your regression, e.g. by adding polynomial terms (e.g. ${x_i}^2$, etc.). The model now becomes $\hat y_i=b_0+b_1.x_i + b_2.{x_i}^2+ ...$. This may, or not, improve things; we would need to see the actual data (scatter plot of $X$ against $Y$) to see what additional terms may improve the fit.
Your question implied that you were looking for a single (constant) value to add to all $X$ measurements to bring them close to $Y$. That is highly unlikely to happen, unless the only significant difference between $X$ and $Y$ is a systematic additive bias. Then that would be obvious from the scatter plot (data is in a straight line, parallel to the identity line). Then (and only then) that value would be the coefficient $b_0$ (and the regression will tell you that the $b_1$ term is not significant -i.e. it does not really help predict $Y$). The more general linear terms allow you to adjust each $x_i$ value; think of it as a sort of calibration (this is exactly how many (most?) measuring instruments are calibrated, as they do not perfectly measure the measurand, but can be calibrated exactly as described here).

I would like to suggest the problem might be far different from this and really needs clarification.  For what I am referring to, please see the link in my comment to the question.

@whuber, interesting take. The op does not mention contour lines or related terms, but instead says "move the second data set, so it matches the first data value  ....  within 5% of the control GPS measurements". It would appear to be a case of "matching" numerical values. But let's see if/how the OP will clarify.

GPS coordinates + "elevations" constitutes a topographic dataset, whether or not contour lines are involved.  That is why I perceived this question as potentially involving considerations similar to the post I referenced, including what kind of adjustment process is involved in "matching" the data.

Some clarification, the first data set, the controlling data, is from GPS measurements taken on the ground, this data set is controlling.  The second data set is from LIDAR that was taken on a cropped area, soybeans to be exact, so the surface provided from the lidar in those areas specifically is in question, but their error should be somewhat uniform.  Using the horizontal values from the GPS data allowed me to get an exact elevation for the LIDAR surface at each of my known GPS values.  Also, I feel as if I have enough representation of GPS vs. LIDAR to be sufficient.  Thank you all again.
